# Genes where both a disabling mutation and copy number amplification cause different genetic diseases

Tags: genetics, gene

I'm trying to make a list of such  genes, because they must be tightly regulated. MeCP2 is one - it causes Rett Syndrome with a disabling mutation, but causes MeCP2 duplication syndrome if its copy number has been increased. Anyone know of any others?

Comment: Must this list include only genes where both deletion and duplication have been shown to have disease phenotypes?  Can this list also include transcripts with dose-dependent pathologies?  *i.e.* genes for which deviations (both up- and down-regulation) from median expression are deleterious?

Comment: @Dirigible yes I think that would be interesting to know as well.